# Why is this enum type not resolved properly?

Tags: java, enums

The following java code doesn't compile in eclipse. What am I doing wrong here? It all works ok if the method just returns an `int` instead of an `enum` so it's basically set up ok. the problem is in introducing the enum return type.

```
public class myclass {
  public enum mytype {
      mytype2,
      mytype1,  
  };
  public static mytype retmytype() {
    return mytype2;
  }
}

//in another class
myclass.mytype t = myclass.retmytype(); //ERROR - myclass.mytype cannot be solved
```

Comment: Use `camelCase` man !

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza inner enums are always static, even if it's not specified

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza if an enum is a member of a class, it's implicitly static

Comment: @Daniel sorry, I forgot it for a minute.

Comment: Besides that in method `retmytype()` you should `return mytype.mytype2;` (the name must be qualified), this should work. The cause of the error is in something you didn't show us. Do you have an old class file `myclass.class` that gets picked up? Are the classes in different packages? Did you import `myclass` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `return mytype2;` by `return mytype.mytype2;`

By the way, you should follow Java naming convention ;)

I think you forgot a main method (or any other called methods in your program flow).
Try this:

```
public class myclass {
  public enum mytype {
      mytype2,
      mytype1,  
  };
  public static mytype retmytype() {
    return mytype.mytype2;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    myclass.mytype t = myclass.retmytype();
  }
}
```

Comment: @glutz You might forget to surround your call with a main method ;) for instance. You might have your call "in the air".